# Ho to fix playsound excpetion "playbin.set_state returned <enum GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE"?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am trying to make a simple metronome in Python using the `playsound` module. But when I run it, there's the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/run/media/mb/Volume/Dokumente/Coding/Python/Metronom/metronom.py", line 5, in <module>
    playsound("Cowbell.wav")   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playsound.py", line 106, in _playsoundNix
    "playbin.set_state returned " + repr(set_result)) 
playsound.PlaysoundException: playbin.set_state returned <enum GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE of type Gst.StateChangeReturn>
```

Comment: I think you need to show us the first 5 lines of `metronom.py`.

Comment: Actually I was just testing the playsound module, so the code is:                      `from playsound import playsound

playsound("Cowbell.wav")`

Answer (score -3):

```
#if its in the same folder as project
playsound('file.mp3')
#somewhere else? then full path (REMEMBER PYTHON USES FORWARDSLASHES /, NOT BACKSLASHES \)
playsound('C:/your/path/to/file.mp3')
```

Also be aware that some files will throw a playsound exception if they have a high enough bitrate (idk why, i suppose playsound cant handle some high quality bitrates)